# How do I limit the snapshot to 1 document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a real-time listener set up, I have ordered the data but I only want to retrieve the latest data value.

I've tried adding .limit(1) but it is not working

```
const callSheet = document.querySelector('#call-sheet');
const form = document.querySelector('#add-call-form');

// create element and render calls
function renderCall(doc){
    // tags
    // unique firestore document id
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let van = document.createElement('span');
    let time = document.createElement('span');
    let ete1 = document.createElement('span');
    let ete2 = document.createElement('span');

    if (doc.data().van == 3) {
        // set document id
        li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);

        // set other data fields
        van.innerHTML = "Van " + doc.data().van + '<br />'
        time.innerHTML = "Last dispatched at " + doc.data().time + '<br />';
        ete1.textContent = "ETE: " + doc.data().ete1 + " - " + doc.data().ete2 + " minutes";

        li.appendChild(van);
        li.appendChild(time);
        li.appendChild(ete1);

        callSheet.appendChild(li);
    }
}

// retrieve the Call Information collection
// snapshot is what you get back from the method call 
// (a representation of the different data in the collection)
// real-time listener:
db.collection('Call Information').orderBy("time", "desc").limit(1).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if(change.type == 'added'){
            renderCall(change.doc)
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = callSheet.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
            callSheet.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
})
```

I am trying to get the latest 1 document for each van, but even though there are documents in the database for each van, when I change the `if (doc.data().van == 3)` to any other value (e.g. 1 or 2), no data is displayed.
If I remove the `orderBy` and `limit`, all the data values are displaying normally for each van.

Comment: What isn't working? As in: what do you expect this code to do when you run it? And what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You mean `limit(1)`?

```
db.collection('Call Information')
  .orderBy("time", "desc")
  .limit(1)
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
```

See the [Firestore documentation on ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).